# ASP.NET MVC - Same authentication between two applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have created two `MVC` applications that share the same authentication. In the applications I'm using different user roles that can be assigned to every user. When I log in as an administrator, everything works fine, I log in to the first application and the same cookie is used to log in to the second application, no login prompts involved.

When I log in as a user with a different role assigned to them, the login screen pops up again after logging in to the first application and it doesn't go away, even if I log in there also.

The applications are both on the same `IIS` server. The machine key is configured correctly in `IIS` server (obviously, since it works if I log in as a user with the administrator role assigned) and here is the code in `Startup.Auth.cs` for both applications:

**1st Application:**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "DefaultCookie",
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

**2nd Application:**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "DefaultCookie",
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("./Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
        OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect
    },
});

private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context)
{
    Uri absoluteUri;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri))
    {
        var path = PathString.FromUriComponent(absoluteUri);
        Trace.WriteLine(path);
        if (path == context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase + context.Options.LoginPath)
            context.RedirectUri = "/Account/Login" +
                new QueryString(
                    context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                    context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an authorization issue, not an authentication issue. If you can share the login *at all*, i.e. in the case of your admin user, then everything is fine on that front. However, the user's role must be authorized to access the controller/action or they will still be redirected to the login page, even though they are already authenticated. This is intended as an opportunity for them to re-authenticate with an account with the appropriate privileges, since the one they used apparently does not have access.

Long an short, you need to ensure that whatever controller(s)/action(s) you want the user to be able to access allow the role that is assigned to them.

Comment: I have the `[Authorize]` line before the controller, do you mean that I should specifically say which roles are authorized? I thought it worked so that all roles are authorized unless otherwise specified.

Comment: You are correct. However, the behavior of your application suggests there is already a role restriction somewhere. Perhaps, a global Authorize attribute has been applied, or maybe specific action(s) have an Authorize attribute with roles applied.

Comment: Yes, you were right! I had missed a `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` in the first application that prevented any other user roles to open the website. Thanks!